# How to configure 3 or more modules in phalcon php

Tags: php, phalcon

Phalcon examples of using modules only have 2 modules example. 
I am trying to create 3 or 4 modules but when i run the application it is still loading the 2 module. 
I want the 3 module to loaded. how can this be done. thanks.

Comment: You are doing something wrong when configuring your modules.

Comment: it was mistake on my part. the config.ini file's content was not changed after i duplicated a module and rename the module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register all of your modules before calling the handle function of your Phalcon Application

```
    $application->registerModules([
        'frontend' => [
            'class' => "Phaltron\\Module",
            'path' => "../apps/Module.php"
        ],
        'backend' => [
            'class' => "Phaltron\\Module",
            'path' => "../apps/Module.php"
        ],
        'api' => [
            'class' => "Phaltron\\Module",
            'path' => "../apps/Module.php"
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: thank you. i finally saw the mistake. i copied a module and renamed the module without changing the config.ini's file content and it was resolved when changed. it actually took a whole day.